# In Angular 2. how do I animate to a certain runtime value?

Tags: javascript, angular, animation

In Angular 2, I want to animate some absolute positioned element to a certain runtime value (as soon as the data is populated). How do I do that ? Can I change the state settings in code? (or with some callback?)

```
@Component({
   animations: [
      trigger('blahState', [
       state ('closed', style({ top: '0px'} )),
       state ('open', style({ top: ??? (<= must be the position of some dom element) })),
       transition('closed => open', animate('500ms ease-in'))])
      ]
})
```

Comment: what do you mean by `must be the position of some dom element`?

Comment: an y position of an HTML element in the page. offsetTop for instance. That position is changed by data.. 

<div>***dynamic content***</div>
<div id="myElement"></div>

And I need to animate to the position of #myElement

Comment: then what about #myElement?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the 'state' in your component class:

for example:

component template:

```
<div [@blahState]="my_animation_state"></div>
```

and component class:

```
  export MyComponent{
     public my_animation_state:string = 'open';
     toggleState() {
        this.my_animation_state == 'open' ? 'closed' : 'open';
     }
  }
```

and you will get the transition when you change state from 'closed' to 'open'

```
transition('closed => open', ...
```

last thing, you can call event when your animation end or start:

```
<div [@blahState]="my_animation_state" (@blahState.done)="animationDone()" (@blahState.start)="animationStart()></div>
```

and your component class:

```
animationStart() {
// your code
}

animationDone(){
// your code
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: that is not really my question. But perhaps it can be done in animationStart.. Can I change the value of the animation at that specific time?

Comment: You can't change component animations after creations.
Just as it is impossible to change `selector`.

If I helped you in some way it would be nice of you to give feedback :)